# move point along a 3d line given by 2 points

Tags: 3d, line

I found a lot of articles about moving the point between two given points, but I just wonder if I have a line, given by two points, e.g. L1, L2 and I would like to get a point P, which lies on a same line but is moved by some distance d.

P<------------------------------L1<----L2

thank you

Comment: for more info, google "parametric line equation"

Answer (score 1):

Let d0 be the distance between L1 and L2.

```
a = d / d0;
P.x = L1.x * (1 - a) + L2.x * a;
P.y = L1.y * (1 - a) + L2.y * a;
```

Comment: d0 is the distance between L1 and L2, but what is d? I assume it's a distance between two points, but which two points? P and L1 maybe?